# How can I add a LinkedIn badge to a Jekyll page?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

How can I properly insert a LinkedIn badge to my GitHub-hosted Jekyll site? I use the jekyll-theme-minimal theme.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about Jekyll and GitHub Pages. It all depends on the theme you use.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, correct, Jekyll on GitHub

Comment: And what did you try? What did you add into `_config.yml`, and how did you reference it? What did you expect to appear, and what did you observe instead?

Comment: I have copied the code provided by linkedIn for the badge, to the _config.yml, I didn't reference it. Is there anywhere general guide that I can find how to update the _config.yml?

Comment: Configuration is described [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/). As far as I can tell from the [jekyll-theme-minimal repo](https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal), the theme doesn't support anything like a LinkedIn badge. I'll add an answer for a general solution.

Comment: actually, I done all again, and it worked, the badge has been added, it has changed a little fonts of my portfolio but not bad :-), thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following the instructions to this [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-linkedin-badge-your-website-amy-wallin/), adding a badge requires to insert something like this into your page:

```html
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js"
  async defer type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="badge-base LI-profile-badge" data-locale="en_US" data-size="medium"
  data-theme="light" data-type="VERTICAL" data-vanity="{PROFILENAME}"
  data-version="v1">
  <a class="badge-base__link LI-simple-link"
    href="https://ca.linkedin.com/in/{PROFILENAME}?trk=profile-badge">{YOUR NAME} 
 </a>
</div>
```

(Line breaks added for readability only.)

You can add that into your `_config.yml`:

```yaml
linkedin_badge: |
  <script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div class="badge-base LI-profile-badge" data-locale="en_US" data-size="medium" data-theme="light" data-type="VERTICAL" data-vanity="{PROFILENAME}" data-version="v1"><a class="badge-base__link LI-simple-link" href="https://ca.linkedin.com/in/{PROFILENAME}?trk=profile-badge">{YOUR NAME}</a></div>
```

And then, on any page where you want to insert the badge, you can use a Liquid tag:

```
Here is my LinkedIn badge:

{{ site.linkedin_badge }}
```

Alternatively, you could put the two lines into a file in the `_includes` directory, e.g., `linkedin_badge.html`, and then include it like this:

```
Here is my LinkedIn badge:

{% include linkedin_badge.html %}
```